# How can I find out if the person sending a slash command is in a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, undefined

Everytime I try to use interaction.member or interaction.user I am encountering the same problem of:
    `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'member')`
Here is my code:

`run: async ({ interaction, client }) =>{ const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel if (!voiceChannel) { return interaction.editReply("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command");}`

Any help understanding why member is undefined is much appreciated.

Comment: Not really because we've got no idea how you call that `run` method. It would be great to also add that part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `member` property that is `undefined`, it is your `interaction` that is `undefined`. Your interaction property has not been defined or you've passed the argument wrong. You need to check if you've used the arguments correctly. As you probably are using an interaction handler, I'd recommend to change the parameters of your run function to `(interaction, client)` instead of `({interaction, client})`.

Comment: Thanks so much managed to get it working now, can I ask why it is better without the braces I've never used javascript before so trying to get used to it.